# Why the huge reference to Chuck Lorre in Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt season 2 episode 2?

Tags: unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt

In season 2 episode 2 of *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt,* about twelve minutes into it there's a discussion between Kimmy and Jacqueline where Kimmy brings up *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles.* Shortly after that she's entering Jacqueline's town house, sings "Heros in a half shell / Turtle power" then says, "Whoever wrote that song deserves to be a billionaire." Immediately she walks by a large poster saying, "Chuck Lorre wrote that song":

[image: Chuck Lorre wrote that song]

[Chuck Lorre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Lorre) did indeed write that song, and he's well known for having created many critically acclaimed and popular sitcoms.

But why such a huge shout-out to Lorre here? As far as I can tell, he didn't have anything to do with this episode. Does he have any connection with *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt?* Or with its writing team? Or is this just some writers tossing some praise his way because they like him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR:

> Does he have any connection with Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt?

No

> Or with its writing team?

No

> Or is this just some writers tossing some praise his way because they like him?

Yes

> Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt’s Writers Walk Us Through Season Two’s Most Memorable Jokes

https://www.vulture.com/2016/04/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-season-two-jokes.html

> Episode Two
>
> Kimmy is entering Jacqueline’s house. Surrounded by moving boxes, Kimmy sings the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles theme song and says, “Whoever wrote that song deserves to be a billionaire.” Kimmy walks out of frame and behind her is a photograph of Chuck Lorre in the style of Barbara Kruger that reads, “Chuck Lorre wrote that song.”
>
> RC: We already had the Turtle thing in place for a long time. The **Chuck Lorre thing**, just **the fact that that guy has another revenue stream**, really, **I’m fascinated with**.
>
> It was something we collectively knew for some reason.
>
> Sam Means: I definitely **pitched that in the room**, but then it was **a question of “Will people think we just made that up?”**
>
> RC: I pitched it being a Barbara Kruger painting. But, yeah, **we were talking about Teenage Mutants Ninja Turtles and we were like, we have to try to find a way to mention that Chuck Lorre is involved. Why not?** We don’t have to cut down to time on Netflix.

Background:

https://www.thewrap.com/kimmy-schmidt-chuck-lorre-write-teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-theme-song/

> The TV producer best known for creating ”Two and a Half Men“ and ”The Big Bang Theory“ has a secret musical past

https://www.indiewire.com/2016/04/chuck-lorre-has-never-met-tina-fey-but-is-flattered-by-his-kimmy-schmidt-reference-289530/

> Of course, **the inside joke** is that Lorre has indeed become extremely successful (if not a billionaire, extremely close) in the years since he wrote “heroes in a half-shell…. Turtle Power!”